# Ошибка Grouper for 'price' not 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

Программа анализирует выборку данных по продажам домов и сохраняет графики зависимостей цены от различных параметром.

Но почему-то выводит ошибку в строке:

```
dataset.pivot_table('price', row[i]).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Вот сам код:

```
#python data analysis library
import csv
from pandas import read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#read dataset.csv file
dataset = read_csv('dataset.csv')
reader = csv.reader(open('dataset.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')


#Show Characteristics-Price Addiction
corr = dataset.corr()._get_item_cache(item='price').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.savefig('Characteristics-Price Addiction.png', format = 'png')
plt.title('House Price Addiction With All Characteristics')
plt.grid()
plt.show()


#save all addiction
for row in reader:
    i = 1
    while (i != 20):
        dataset.pivot_table('price', row[i]).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
        plt.savefig('price-' + row[i] + ' addiction', format='png')
        i += 1
    break
```

Ошибка:

> Grouper for 'price' not 1-dimensional

Comment: вы как-то очень странно используете Pandas... Зачем вам `csv.reader` если вы уже прочитали те же данные в DataFrame `dataset`? Вы можете выложить свой CSV файл на какой-нибудь файло-обменник (например: http://dropmefiles.com/) и кратко объяснить что вы хотите "нарисовать"?

Comment: Вы хотите вывести 20 графиков зависимости цены от остальных колонок из CSV файла? Тогда у вас ошибка в логике использования `pivot_table()` - в качестве индекса надо указать имя колонки, а не значение: `row[i]`

Comment: Я считываю Reader-ом первую строку, где находятся 20 параметров квартиры, относительно которых строится зависимость. Далее я перебираю все в цикле все 20 параметров, подставляя их в переменную, поочередно выстраивая графики зависимостей. Только выдает ошибку.

Comment: вы хотите построить 20 графиков всего или же 20 графиков для каждой квартиры?

Comment: Всего 20 графиков. Общая зависимость параметров по всей выборке.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

D:\temp\price-bedrooms-addiction.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот рабочий пример:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# т.к. вы не предоставили примера CSV воспользуемся случайными данными...    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5, 20)),columns=['p{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,21)])
df['price'] = np.random.randint(10**5, 10**7, 5)

for c in df.columns.difference(['price']).tolist():
    df.set_index(c)['price'].plot.bar(stacked=True)
    plt.savefig('d:/temp/price-{}-addiction.png'.format(c))
```

результаты:

D:\temp\price-p1-addiction.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

D:\temp\price-p2-addiction.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

D:\temp\price-p3-addiction.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и т.д.

Если же вы хотите видеть на одном графике зависимость цены от всех параметров:

```
In [98]: df.set_index('price').plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True, figsize=(16, 12))
Out[98]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x932eb70>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как понять теперь где какой график то?

Comment: ну как бы по названию и по наименованию X-оси

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1FYAxi6edM6UTRxSTk3c2hTVjA

Comment: Не могли бы вы сделать его на примере моей выборки? Ибо ничего не понятно. Ночь уже :с

Comment: @Aндрей, что должно быть в качестве оси `X` в графиках - цена или параметр (один из 20-ти)?

Comment: Я думаю, что стоит разместить параметр

Comment: @Aндрей, с таким количеством данных все подписи на оси `X` сливаются, поэтому вам это ничего не даст...

Comment: Да, я знаю. Пусть пока что будет так, а дальше разберусь как быть.